# Width auto not updating with knockout text bind

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

Okay, so I just started working on a on-going project. I noticed a bug to where the user name would appear inside another element until a cursor hovered over it.

After much investigation I found that this was due to the fact that this project uses Knockout.js. For a placeholder in the span element they had a no-break space. So when the page rendered it would sometimes forget to update the width auto with the newly changed text.

```
<span data-bind="text: db.who">&nbsp;</span>
<!--and updates to-->
<span data-bind="text: db.who">Username</span>
<!--however, ^this^ updated version does not allow for the width: auto to work.-->
```

I am open to answers that involve html, css, javascript, and/or JQuery

Comment: Could you add surrounding markup or jsfiddle? How can it be "sometimes" - i.e. sometimes it works as expected?

Comment: It "sometimes" works because of how browsers render pages. It usually works as expected _if_ the connection with the server is a fast one.

Answer (score 0):

Fot this you need to use attr binding like this

```
<span data-bind="text: db.who,attr:{width:SetWidth}">Username</span>

self.SetWidth = function(){
    return 'auto'
}
```

This will be applied dynamically so when the page is rendered knockout will call SetWidth function to return something and apply it on element

Comment: It did not work. Perhaps my diagnostic is wrong. I am working on the MineOS UI page. You can view my fork at:
https://github.com/MDooley47/mineos

(it is located in html > index_en.html)